# Can you suggest text editor (linux) that has good customisation of highlighting?

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, highlighting

I need a editor in which I could customise highlighting so that it could highlight sentences in which bad programming style (I have my own rules for this) would be underlined.
example "if(a==1)DoSomething();" would be underlined, and "if ( a == 1 ) DoSomething();" won't be underlined. Which text editor allows such customisation?

Comment: thats a very good question to start a flamewar of vim vs. emacs...

Comment: I believe that there are existing tools which do this for Eclipse already.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Why do you think so? I don't see anything provocative in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why, [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) of course. Both are *very* customizable - whether you're leaning more towards regex/Vimscript/Python/Ruby/Perl or ELISP will probably decide your favourite. ELISP is somewhat more structured, and Emacs highlighter is a bit better, but unless you've worked with LISP before, it will look like chaos. The first bunch of languages are probably more familiar to you (since they're rather *mainstream* nowadays). In either case, don't expect big results in an afternoon.

Comment: I'm a little pessimistic about making a complete coding style checker for vi/emacs (otherwise, surely, there would already be support for that).  Not that it can't be done, but it will be quite an effort (design/implementation/testing) especially if you want to allow custom rules.  Personally, I would use an external enforcer like pc-lint during compile-time.  However, looking at the upvotes, many must have already done this, which means I'm wrong.

Comment: @stefaanv - No, I don't think they have. I've tried messing with Vim's highlighting once and agree, it's quite an effort to write them from scratch (with Python it's a little better, but only a little). Most of these upvotes are a result of just mentioning one of these two :/

Comment: @Rook: too bad, this is one of the cases, where I'd prefer to be wrong ;)

Comment: @stefaanv : The OP is asking about editor that can customize there ability to find certain segments of customizable text and apply colour highlighting. Though most editors allow you to specify colours very few (vi/emacs are probably the only two) that you allow you to customize what is highlighted and how.

Comment: @Martin - Yes. There are two ways do do it in Vi. One is to modify the original (over-read it with your own) syntax file, which is not so easy for people who are not at first terms with regex and the language who's syntax file they're modifying. The other is to create highlighting groups to highlight specific cases. That could end up a s a lot of highlighting groups, but it is an easier way, and could just satisfy the OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs - much od it is written in e-lisp which is the language users can customise it with so you would have comprehensive access to changing the formatting of the data,

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). It's a highly customizable code editor.
I don't know how to customize the highlighting but it's definitely possible and they have a forum with helpful users.

Comment: Development of ST2 could really benefit from some decent documentation. I saw the editor once or twice, used it, really liked it, but in comparison to let's say, Vim, its docs. are non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether such an editor exists, but there are tools that do style checking and print a report. See for example [cpplint.py](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py) that is recommended in [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml).

Comment: Google C=+ Style guide is good for google code to make sure you don't break backward compatibility. It is not considered a good general C++ style guide.